# Merging nested dictonaries in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, merge

For some real time data representation I'm using two dictionaries that have to be merged:

```
 //Orderdata string,orderdetails int,day int,hour int,count
 var OldData = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>>>();
 var TodayData = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>>>();
```

What is the best to merge these two dictionaries?

In this situation I'm sure there are some duplicates

Comment: Firstly, I'd consider changing your data structure to start with. That's horribly deep nesting - if you created named types with clear meanings which *contained* dictionaries, it would be a lot easier to understand. It would also give you somewhere to put a `Merge` method at each level...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will merge the dictionaries at each level. You'll need to be clear on what you want to do at the 'leaf' level though, since in this case values which have the same compound key through all the nested dictionaries will just be replaced from oldData into todayData.

```
private void MergeDictionaries()
{
    var oldData = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>>>();
    var todayData = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>>>();

    foreach (var kvp in oldData)
    {
        Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>> today;
        if (!todayData.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out today))
        {
            today = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>>();
            todayData.Add(kvp.Key, today);
        }

        foreach (var kvp2 in kvp.Value)
        {
            Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> today2;
            if (!today.TryGetValue(kvp2.Key, out today2))
            {
                today2 = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>();
                today.Add(kvp2.Key, today2);
            }

            foreach (var kvp3 in kvp2.Value)
            {
                Dictionary<int, int> today3;
                if (!today2.TryGetValue(kvp3.Key, out today3))
                {
                    today3 = new Dictionary<int, int>();
                    today2.Add(kvp3.Key, today3);
                }

                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp4 in kvp3.Value)
                {
                    // What you do here determines what happens when there are key duplicates
                    today3[kvp4.Key] = kvp4.Value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also achieve similar results with a lot less code using Linq's `SelectMany` function.

Comment: Yes you could, but to deal with the deep nesting would lead to some quite ugly LINQ I reckon. Also anything usng LINQ has to go via IEnumerable, then recreate an entirely new dictionary, rather than merging elements of one into the other.

Comment: I was hoping for a function called Merge that did this or a simple Extension method to do this. The last value is a count that can be simply be summed where needed. However the given solution fits the question nicely, thanks!.

Comment: It may suit the way you access or manipulate the data to use the nested dictionary construct, however aside from Mr Skeet's suggestion to create your own types rather than directly use Dictionary, you could also simplify the process of accessing and merging your data structure by using Dictionary<Tuple<string, int, int, int>, int> instead of the nested dictionary. This works because comparing two tuples will automatically compare each element in turn.